# AWS GO SDK - EC2 Launch Templates - Get oldest version

Tags: amazon-web-services, go

Is there a way to request the oldest version of an AWS EC2 launch template using the AWS GO SDK?

For example, DescribeLaunchTemplateVersions will return information about launch templates over a range of versions, between minVersion and maxVersion:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/ec2/#EC2.DescribeLaunchTemplateVersions

Given a launch template, is there a way I can determine the oldest (minVersion?) of that launch template using the AWS GO SDK?

This is what I am trying to determine programatically using GO SDK:

```
 // The version number after which to describe launch template versions.
    MinVersion *string `type:"string"`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this using: DescribeLaunchTemplateVersions

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/ec2/#EC2.DescribeLaunchTemplateVersions